# Android Studio and Chaquopy debug python code

Tags: python, android-studio, chaquopy

I am using Chaquopy in an AndroidStudio android project.
Executing my python code works fine, but I would like to set breakpoints in the python code and while debugging the android app examine the python variables.
AndroidStudio prompts "No Python interpreter configured for the module". I tried to configure one using

Tools -> "Sync Python requirements" -> "Configure a Python Interpreter"

but when I do the project can not be run as before, because there is no Android SDK selected afterwards. Executing gradle resets everything to the original state.

Is it at all possible to debug the python code in an Android project?
How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of Chaquopy. I don't have a simple answer to this question, but there are some notes [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/1050) which you might find useful.